# Azure Devops Pipeline - copy file from template repo to /build or into published artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo with build and publish templates. It also has a common file 'common.json'

template repo structure

```
- bicep
- pipelines
  - build.yml
  - publish.yml
  - common.json
```

When called from another repo's pipeline the 'build.yml' template file will build and publish a build artifact.

I need a copy the `common.json` file into the '/build' folder.

This is my template. Ive tried a bunch of things including publishing the `common.json', the copy task.

Also this pipeline runs multiple times (there are multiple environemnts/stages)

Any ideas?

```
parameters:
  - name: 'environment'
    type: 'string'
    default: 'development'
  - name: 'variableGroup'
    type: 'string'
    default: development-variables'
  - name: 'buildRoot'
    type: 'string'
    default: 'app'
  - name: 'buildCMD'
    type: 'string'
    default: 'build'
  - name: 'buildFolder'
    type: string
    default: '/dist'
  - name: 'nodeVersion'
    type: string
    default: '16.x'
  - name: environmentVariables
    type: object
    default: {}
    
jobs:
  - job: build_project_for_${{parameters.environment}}
    variables:
      - group: ${{parameters.variableGroup}}
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
        
      - task: UseNode@1
        displayName: 'Install Node v${{ parameters.nodeVersion }}'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: ${{ parameters.nodeVersion }}
      
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Build for production'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |        
            npm ci 
            npm run ${{ parameters.buildCMD }}
        env: 
           ${{ each pair in parameters.environmentVariables }}:
            ${{ pair.Key }}: $(echo ${{ pair.Value }} | base64 --decode | yaml)

      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '/'
          Contents: 'common.json'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{parameters.buildFolder}}'
          OverWrite: true      
      
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish'
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{parameters.buildFolder}}'
          artifactName: ${{ parameters.environment }}
```